# SharedPreferences saves, doesn't persist on next launch

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

My `Storyteller` class interacts with SharedPreferences.

It loads a StringSet from SharedPreferences with a default value containing 22 strings, saving in its `chapters` variable.

When a "complete" event occurs later in the program, the `Storyteller` removes a String from `chapters`, then commits this to SharedPreferences.

My logs show 22 strings loaded at first, then 21 after removing and committing to the editor.

When I run the program again, 22 chapters are loaded instead of the expected 21.

```
  private Set<String> chapters;

    protected Storyteller(Context c) {
        buffer = "";
        choices = new JSONArray();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = c.getSharedPreferences(c.getString(R.string.pref_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        chapters = sharedPref.getStringSet("chapters", new HashSet<String>());
        Log.v("sip", chapters.toString());
        Log.v("sip-loaded", String.valueOf(chapters.size()));

        if (chapters.isEmpty()) {
            Log.v("sip", "saving vignettes");
            ArrayList<String> names = vignettes();
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
                String name = names.get(i);
                chapters.add(name);
            }
            editor.putStringSet(c.getString(R.string.chapters), chapters);
            editor.commit();
        }
        Log.v("sip", String.valueOf(chapters.size()));
    }




public void complete(String chapter, Context c) {
    chapters.remove(chapter);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = c.getSharedPreferences(c.getString(R.string.pref_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(c.getString(R.string.chapters), chapters);
    editor.commit();
    Log.v("sip", String.valueOf(chapters.size()));
    chapters = sharedPref.getStringSet("chapters", new HashSet<String>());
    Log.v("sip", String.valueOf(chapters.size()));
}
```

Logs from first run:

```
12-10 15:24:27.161 3241-3241/? V/sip-loaded: 22
12-10 15:24:27.161 3241-3241/? V/sip: 22
12-10 15:24:27.161 3241-3241/? V/sip-storyloaded: Story loaded
12-10 15:24:37.409 3241-3241/coffeechoices.quantumproductions.com.choicescoffee V/sip: 21
12-10 15:24:37.409 3241-3241/coffeechoices.quantumproductions.com.choicescoffee V/sip: 21
12-10 15:24:37.409
```

Logs from second run:

```
12-10 15:25:34.097 3307-3307/coffeechoices.quantumproductions.com.choicescoffee V/sip-loaded: 22
12-10 15:25:34.097 3307-3307/coffeechoices.quantumproductions.com.choicescoffee V/sip: 22
12-10 15:25:34.098 3307-3307/coffeechoices.quantumproductions.com.choicescoffee V/sip-storyloaded: Story loaded
```

EDIT:

getString(R.string.chapters) is `chapters`, see Strings file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">choices.coffee</string>
    <string name="pref_key">choices.coffee</string>
    <string name="chapters">chapters</string>
</resources>
```

I was trying using "chapters" and getString, same result.

Notice that after I save in the `complete` function, I'm able to read from file and it shows the correct amount, 21. When I restart, it's 22, but my log for creating the dataset fresh (only happens when the set is empty) doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different keys: `R.string.chapters` and `"chapters"`.

I'll assume they don't equate to the same String.  Switch too using only one key value.

---

**EDIT**:

You should never change `chapters` directly according to the documentation for [SharedPreferences.getStringSet()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)):

> Note that you *must not* modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all.

Comment: <resources>
    <string name="chapters">chapters</string>
</resources>

Comment: Have you rerun your app with only one key reference? Regardless of whether this is the current problem, this will likely be a problem someday.

Comment: What do you mean 1 key reference? I tried again using R.string.chapters in all places, same result. It's strange that when I write, then load, 21 shows up but on start new app it's back to 22.

Comment: Hmm, check out my updated answer.  You need to make a deep copy of the Set returned from the Editor.  Also could you use more specific tags in you Logcat output?  Having "sips" everywhere isn't helping when I cannot see all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Call `.clear()`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = c.getSharedPreferences(c.getString(R.string.pref_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.clear();
```

allows it to save correctly.